# Checkbox value `on` is not submitted to Action class. Shall I get parameter from HttpServletRequest directly?

Tags: html, checkbox, struts2, struts2-interceptors, struts-tags

I want to submit a form to my action class with Struts 2 classic `getter/setter` way. All other fields get their value, except for a `boolean` field, which stays being `false` when I check the checkbox it corresponds.

I have a checkbox like this in my jsp:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <input class="input-md" type="checkbox" id="soloIdaId" name="soloIda" />
</div>
```

And in my action class I have:

```
private boolean soloIda;
```

and its getter/setter. But it stays to be false when I checked it.

I noticed that in the `queryString` contains:

```
...&soloIda=on&... (I am testing with FF)
```

And, if I try to get the parameter of request, I get `true`:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
String soloIdaParam = request.getParameter("soloIda"); //"true" when I debug
```

Don't know if this matters, but I am using my interceptor. But I always include the `defaultStack`, and I believe the default interceptor is handling this kind of job(using getter/setter to assign values to fields). So why?

Attaching my `struts.xml` here:

```
 <interceptors>
    <interceptor name="authentication"
        class="com.WindThunder.interceptor.LoginInterceptor">
    </interceptor>
    <interceptor name="query"
        class="com.WindThunder.interceptor.QueryInterceptor">
    </interceptor>
    <interceptor-stack name="authStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="authentication"></interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> <!-- this
          line is necessary for every stack!!!! -->
    </interceptor-stack>
    <interceptor-stack name="pageStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="query"></interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<action name="searchCiudad" class="com.WindThunder.action.VueloAction"
      method="searchCiudad">
<interceptor-ref name="pageStack"/>
  <result name="success">/listaCiudads.jsp</result>
  <result name="error">/common/error.jsp</result>
  <result name="vacio">/common/listaVacia.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And my `QueryInterceptor.java`:

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    //get previous action name = pagePath. (/searchxxx.action)
    this.session = invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String path = request.getRequestURI(); //contaits domain
    String pagePath = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"));

    //get previous query string (param1=xx&param2=xx, or null)
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    addParamToSession(queryString, session);
    String prePage = "";
    if (!pagePath.equalsIgnoreCase("/login.action")){
        prePage = pagePath;
    }
    if (prePage != null && !prePage.equals("")){
        session.put("prePage",prePage);
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

Now I want to get the parameter `"soloIda"` directly from `request` and do some manual assignment, but I think it is Struts 1's way of working. Any idea why it is not working? I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your Interceptor's fault... it's just that checkboxes are an *ugly thing*.

Things to know:

1. What browsers send for checkboxes when a value is not specified is browser-specific;
2. Browsers don't send anything for unchecked values (this may be irrelevant in case of Booleans because the default is false, but still...)

Then you could force the value with

```xml
<input class = "input-md"
        type = "checkbox" 
          id = "soloIdaId" 
        name = "soloIda" 
       value = "true" />
```

and then you'd need to deal with unckecked values.

To handle this situation, Struts2 provides you the [`<s:checkbox />`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/checkbox.html) (and the `<s:checkboxlist />`) tag, with its `value` and `fieldValue` attributes, and the hidden parameter (`__checkbox_something`) that the tag generates to send something even when the checkbox is not checked. This parameter is then read by the [Checkbox Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/checkbox-interceptor.html).

Eg. from the docs:

```xml
<s:checkbox cssClass = "input-md"
                  id = "soloIdaId"
                name = "soloIda" 
          fieldValue = "true"
               value = "aBoolean" 
/>
```

will translate to the following HTML (with Simple Theme and `Boolean aBoolean = true;`):

```xml
<input type = "checkbox" 
      class = "input-md"
         id = "soloIdaId"
       name = "soloIda" 
      value = "true" 
    checked = "checked"
/>
<input type = "hidden"  
         id = "__checkbox_soloIdaId" 
      value = "true" 
       name = "__checkbox_soloIda" 
/>
```

Read the [Mkyong example on `<s:checkbox />`](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/) and also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661060/1654265) to better understand where to start.

Always consider using the framework specific tags (at least at first), that already handles many problems for you transparently.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I don't know why but `<s:checkbox>` is not following my Boostrap CSS rules while `<input type="checkbox">` is fine. And at last, so I decided to use `<input>` and get the parameters from `HttpServletSession` directly.... But anyway thanks. It's not a project for production just a homework to do so I am often getting my hands dirty right now. But I will accept your answer and save it for furture use coz you are providing great references and much info here.

Comment: @FaithReaper don't give up: I know *exactly* why it doesn't follow your Bootstrap CSS rules, [it's all explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28558436/1654265). Then, if you are not using the Bootstrap Plugin (and you don't need to, if you already know how to write plain Bootstrap), simply add `theme="simple"` to your `<s:checkbox/>` tags. That's it. I suggest you to try even if you've already moved on after this, in order to learn the best practices instead of the voodoo you've ended up with. Please consider **upvoting** the answer(s) that helped you, it's the best thank for their authors

Comment: I tried `theme="simple"` and it worked, great! But I cannot submit my value to my action class, which is an `Integer`. When I tick this checkbox, I want to pass the `ID` of this flight to my class but it's not working(error in console: `Missing key [invalid.fieldvalue.reservaChecked] in bundles [[org/apache/struts2/struts-messages, com/opensymphony/xwork2/xwork-messages]]!` while I have set `fieldValue="true"`. But `<input type="radio"/>` is working. Besides, I want it to be single-selected, not multiple-selcted.

Comment: You still haven't up-voted any answer :( BTW you should edit your question adding the details because in comment it is very difficult to get them; that said, I guess that with your last `<input type="radio"/>` is a typo for  `<input type="checkbox"/>`, otherwise I'm lost. Also reservaChecked is not in your code, but it is in your error message, that however seems to be i18n related... meh

Comment: I have voted up your answer, and no, it´s not a typo: `radio` is working for me but `checkbox` and `s:checkbox` is not. And, as I only want to select one option, and `radio` allows me to do it (and `checkbox` doesn't), so I chose `radio` at last. `reservaChecked` is a `List<Integer>` I defined in my action class, to receive all checkbox/radio, if there's more than one `<input>` with different values but same name. I may edit my question later and thanks anyway.

Comment: Absolutely: if you have multiple choices, use a checkbox, if you have a single choice, use a radio. Checkboxes on a single choice are just the wrong tools for the job. Thank you for the upvote, and consider opening a new question if the edit part changes this question substantially, otherwise just warn me of the edit